# Struts2 custom login interceptor

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2

Can someone explain me how to write a custom login interceptor that checks username, password and also checks if the users validity date is greater than the current date. Im  new to java programming & struts 2...i would really appreciate step by step info. I get the username, etc info by manual jdbc connection...i have a jndi setup for that. This also needs to have session management.

So a step by step with the following code samples would be nice,

1) The dao using jndi to get username,etc from DB

2) The login action with session aware

3) interceptor

4) login.jsp

5) struts.xml definition for the interceptor

6) task.jsp and task2.jsp ( internal pages that can only be seen if user is logged in)

Thank you!

Comment: I'm really skeptical this is something you want to do in an interceptor; why do you want to do this in an interceptor instead of in a login action?

Comment: wouldnt using an interceptor be a better way of doing it?? arent interceptors auto executed before and after an action is called??

Comment: Yes, interceptors wrap action execution. No, it wouldn't be better. Interceptors are designed for site-wide behavior. Checking login doesn't need to happen on every single request.

Comment: Ok so i do the login logic in the LoginAction and than how do i check in all my other 'x' number of pages if my logged in user is valid and that their session has not timed out?? if timer out, than login again.

Comment: Check the session for a valid `user` object (or whatever you're using). If it's not there, redirect to a global login action.

Comment: Now this check will need to be done in all my x pages right? instead of implementing this is all my pages can i not write an interceptor to do this and which will also called before any of my page loads. would this not be a better way?

Comment: Please listen carefully to what I'm saying: login itself should be handled by an action. Checking that someone has logged in, e.g., looking in session for a valid user object, should be in an interceptor.

Comment: Ok thank you...that helps... Can you tel me how to write this interceptor? so i just check if say, Integer userId = (Integer) session.get("userId") than than see if userId!=null .....

Comment: Something like that, yes; you'd remove the session object on logout, and it would be cleared automatically when the session expired. For very-high security you may actually *want* to go against the database or include some mechanism to disable/re-auth users immediately; it depends on your exact needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right track.

There are many articles on that topic (google it). Choose one and try to understand it. The interceptor part should look something like this:

```
public String intercept (ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    // Get the action context from the invocation so we can access the
    // HttpServletRequest and HttpSession objects.
    final ActionContext context = invocation.getInvocationContext ();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.get(HTTP_REQUEST);
    HttpSession session =  request.getSession (true);

    // Is there a "user" object stored in the user's HttpSession?
    Object user = session.getAttribute (USER_HANDLE);
    if (user == null) {
        // The user has not logged in yet.

        // Is the user attempting to log in right now?
        String loginAttempt = request.getParameter (LOGIN_ATTEMPT);
        if (! StringUtils.isBlank (loginAttempt) ) { // The user is attempting to log in.

            // Process the user's login attempt.
            if (processLoginAttempt (request, session) ) {
                // The login succeeded send them the login-success page.
                return "login-success";
            } else {
                // The login failed. Set an error if we can on the action.
                Object action = invocation.getAction ();
                if (action instanceof ValidationAware) {
                    ((ValidationAware) action).addActionError ("Username or password incorrect.");
                }
            }
        }

        // Either the login attempt failed or the user hasn't tried to login yet, 
        // and we need to send the login form.
        return "login";
    } else {
        return invocation.invoke ();
    }
}
```

Above code sample is part of this [article](http://www.vitarara.org/cms/struts_2_cookbook/creating_a_login_interceptor) where you will also find other steps.

Another way I would recommend is integration of spring security with Struts 2. That way you get secured and proven configurable security stack.

Comment: Be wary of posting link-only answers; they're generally frowned upon--answers should stand on their own without having to click through to other resources.

Comment: That's true... But the answer would be rather long... What do you think?

Comment: I think what I said :) The basics of how an interceptor would perform the task can be wrapped up in a few lines of code, the rest is boilerplate and configuration.

Comment: You're right... But @rr87 would like to have step by step info of whole example (steps from 1 to 6 in his question)...

Comment: Perhaps, but IMO the question is too broad if you pay attention to the OP's bullet list, where they're basically asking "write me a complete Struts 2 application with DB access, custom interceptors, and a few framework-specific things". They're basically asking to be pointed at the Struts 2 documentation and showcase apps, which is inappropriate, IMO, and shows zero initiative. The main thrust of the question is where, and how, to process the login, and instrument an app-wide valid login check.

Comment: You've a point. So it's better to not even post answers like this?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure! [I asked on meta about it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145900/how-link-only-does-a-post-need-to-be-before-its-link-only), in fact, because I think your point that the original question was asking for more than could be expressed in a reasonable answer is valid.

Comment: It was interesting debate on meta... It really explains how to write an answers that are based on links..

Comment: Yep, it helped frame how I'll think about it in the future-it's one of the great things about SO, too.